# Can't install crossbar.io binary package on FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: freebsd, crossbar

I'm unable to install the crossbar.io WAMP router's binary distro on FreeBSD 10.1

I'm doing it step-by-step by the manual (http://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-FreeBSD/), but during the `pkg install crossbar` i get this output:

```
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
Fetching meta.txz: 100%    944 B   0.9kB/s    00:01
Fetching packagesite.txz: 100%    6 MiB   2.9MB/s    00:02
Processing entries: 100%
FreeBSD repository update completed. 25427 packages processed.
Updating crossbar repository catalogue...
crossbar repository is up-to-date.
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The following 1 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

New packages to be INSTALLED:
    crossbar: 0.13.2 [crossbar]

Number of packages to be installed: 1

The process will require 161 MiB more space.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[1/1] Installing crossbar-0.13.2...
[1/1] Extracting crossbar-0.13.2:   0%
pkg: Directory /opt/crossbar/lib-python/2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/SystemEvents not specified in the manifest
[1/1] Extracting crossbar-0.13.2: 100%
```

And nothing's get installed only empty folders under `/opt/crossbar`

Am I doing something wrong?

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: It's really interesting point. I think the ideal way (but long) is to create port and publish in freebsd-ports repo. The problem is that "/opt/crossbar" should be like "/usr/local/crossbar" or smth under "/usr/local".

Comment: that would be an ideal solution